# roll a four-sided die and show that the events are independent

Tags: probability, independence

Roll a four-sided die with numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$ each with equal probability. Let $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1,3\}$. Verify that they are independent.

In my opinion, $P(A) = \frac 2 4$ and $P(B) = P(A)$ because the numbers get rolled at random with equal probability. Then $P(A \cap B) = \frac 3 4$. In my book it says that $P(A \cap B) = \frac 1 4$. Can someone explain to me why I am wrong (if I am wrong)?

Comment: $A\cap B$ is the event "you roll a $1$" so of course the answer is $\frac 14$.  Why would you think it was $\frac 34$?  That's greater than $P(A)$ or $P(B)$.

Comment: What do you think $a\cap b$ means?

Comment: Oh, you are thinking of union, not intersection.  It is certainly true that $P(A\cup B)=\frac 34$.

Comment: @lulu oh exactly! thank you!!!

Comment: Think of $\cup$ like a big bag in which you put all of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A\cap B)=P(\{1\})=\frac 14$$
Remark: It is perhaps surprising at first sight is that the knowledge that either $1$ or $2$ occurred does not make the event $\{1,3\}$ more likely, because it feels that we "rule out" $4$ altogether. But that is in fact a fallacious way of thinking. If you know that $\{1,2\}$ occurred, then $\{1,3\}$ occurs in case you got $1$, and did not occur in case you got $2$. The probability of $\{1,3\}$ is still $0.5$, the same as it is with no information.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of the union! Yes, I understand!

Comment: @mandella I see. You're welcome.